# How to render view to string in ASP.NET MVC4 Api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-web-api, razor-2

ASP.NET MVC4 Web API controller should return Razor view as html in json result property.

I tried controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var body = RenderViewToString<object>("~/Views/Broneeri/Schedule.cshtml", new object() );
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { content = body } );
    }

    string RenderViewToString<T>(string viewName, T model)
    {
        ViewDataDictionary ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
        TempDataDictionary TempData = new TempDataDictionary();
        ControllerContext controllerContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext();
        controllerContext.RouteData = new RouteData();

        controllerContext.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", "Schedule");
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData,          
                       TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
 }
```

but I got a strange exception

```
System.NotImplementedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467263
  Message=The method or operation is not implemented.
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.HttpContextBase.get_Items()
       at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
       at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator)
...
```

at line

```
var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
```

How to return HTML content from view in ASP.NET 4 Web API controller?

Comment: WebAPI was meant for REST style operations. If you are returning HTML, why not just use a normal controller action and a partial view?

Comment: WebAPI method returns json data. One property of this data contains response data html format. This content is added to page as html to avoid full page refresh. Thus I need to generate html from WebAPI

Comment: I posted related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854342/exception-in-mono-system-web-rendering-view-in-asp-net-web-api-controller This contains answer which does not work in Mono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Install-Package RazorEngine` using your NuGet console. Here is code that worked for me:

```
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating;

string razorTemplate = "Hello @Model!";
string html = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(
    razorTemplate, 
    "uniqueTemplateKey", // Guid.NewGuid().ToString() for example
    modelType: typeof(string), 
    model: "Lorem Ipsum");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: NuGet package RazorEngine does not belong to Mircrosoft and is not a part of ASP.NET.  Although this answer should work for rendering a Razor view into a string, I think this should still be mentioned.

Comment: @Dimskiy Do you know if there is a similar package from Microsoft to be used inside a .NET Core Api ?

Comment: @bbrinck I'm using RazorLight these days. It's not great but gets the job done...